# Hilbert's Theorem 90 for infinite extensions

Tags: galois-theory, galois-cohomology

I have proven Hilbert's Theorem 90 for finite extensions, that is for a finite Galois extension of fields $L/K$ with Galois group $G$, $H^{1}(G,L^{\times})=1$.

I'm unsure as to how to proceed to the infinite case. I was hoping that I might be able to use the fact that Galois groups of infinite extensions are profinite groups in some nice way.

Comment: Show that inverse limits behave in the expected way under cohomology.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I just assumed they didn't for some reason.

Comment: By definition, Galois cohomology deals with profinite groups G (= inverse limit of finite groups) acting on discrete modules M (= direct limits of abstract modules). So infinite Hilbert's 90 is almost an immediate consequence of the usual finite H.'s 90.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L/K$ be an infinite (algebraic) Galois extension.
You are completely right about the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ being a profinite group. More precisely, $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is the inverse limit of the groups $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$ where $M$ runs over the *finite* Galois extensions $M/K$, with transition morphisms being the restrictions $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K) \to \mathrm{Gal}(M'/K)$ whenever $M' \subset M$ (see Proposition 2.3.1 in [Sharifi's notes](http://math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/groupcoh.pdf)).

By proposition 2.2.16 in [Sharifi's notes](http://math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/groupcoh.pdf), the first continuous cohomology group of $L^{\times}$ is
$$H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(L/K), L^{\times}) \cong \varinjlim\limits_{\substack{M/K \\ \text{finite Galois}}} H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(M/K), M^{\times})$$
where the direct limit is taken with respect to inflation maps. You already know that $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(M/K), M^{\times})$ vanishes, whenever $M/K$ is finite and Galois. Therefore the direct limit above is trivial, showing that  $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(L/K), L^{\times}) = \{0\}$ as wanted.

Comment: Similarly, you can show that $H^n(\mathrm{Gal}(L/K), (L,+)) = 0$ when $n>0$ and $L/K$ is Galois, possibly infinite (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307229)).

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338233/why-is-h1-textgal-overlinek-k-a-lim-rightarrowh1-leftl-k-a-te).